# Get range top values and display in other sheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a woorkbook with a sheet thas has in one column the vendor name, and two columns after the total sales.
In other sheet i want to select and display, in one column(cells) the top five best sales (number) and in the next column(cells) the first and last name of the vender.

I'am trying to solve this, but i dont understand a much of vba.
I tried this, but only get the value.

```
Sub best()
Dim FirstHt As String
Dim SecondHt As String
Dim ThirdHt As String
Dim FourthHt As String
Dim FifthHt As String

FirstHt = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), 1)
          Sheets("os melhores").Range("F30") = FirstHt
SecondHt = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), 2)
          Sheets("os melhores").Range("F31") = SecondHt
ThirdHt = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), 3)
          Sheets("os melhores").Range("F32") = ThirdHt
FourthHt = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), 4)
          Sheets("os melhores").Range("F33") = FourthHt
FifthHt = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), 5)
          Sheets("os melhores").Range("F34") = FifthHt
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort your first page(Name A, Value B), take the 5 highest values, and print them on sheet to from greatest to lowest.

```
Sub Testsort()
Dim LastRow As Long, one As Long, two As Long, three As Long, four As Long, five As Long, onename As String, twoname As String, threename As String, fourname As String, fivename As String


Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
one = Cells((LastRow), "B").Value
onename = Cells((LastRow), "A")
two = Cells((LastRow - 1), "B").Value
twoname = Cells((LastRow - 1), "A")
three = Cells((LastRow - 2), "B").Value
threename = Cells((LastRow - 2), "A")
four = Cells((LastRow - 3), "B").Value
fourname = Cells((LastRow - 3), "A")
five = Cells((LastRow - 4), "B").Value
fivename = Cells((LastRow - 4), "A")


Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells(1, "A") = onename
Cells(1, "B") = one
Cells(2, "A") = twoname
Cells(2, "B") = two
Cells(3, "A") = threename
Cells(3, "B") = three
Cells(4, "A") = fourname
Cells(4, "B") = four
Cells(5, "A") = fivename
Cells(5, "B") = five

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No VBA is actually needed for this.

The `=LARGE(array,k)` function can be used to return the largest, second largest, third largest and kth largest values from a range.

We can also use the `=MATCH (lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])` function  and `INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])` function to get variable names.

Refer to http://www.excel-user.com/2011/02/large-functionget-top-n-values-from.html for a further guide.

Comment: Hi Josh, I've tried it, but i cant figure it out on duplicates, and it passes all the names and not only the first and last. I would prefer a vba aproach. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will deal with duplicates also.

My code takes value from below columns. If you have any change you can change in code.

Sheet 1 (data taken) - J has the sales amount , G has vendor details

Sheet2 (data copied) - F sales amount , G vendor first name , H vendor last name details

```
Sub best()
Dim maxvalue As Long
Dim copyrow As Long
copyrow = 30
Dim prevval As Long
Dim prevrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim fndrow As Long

prevval = 0
prevrow = 0

For i = 1 To 5
maxvalue = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), i)

If maxvalue <> prevval Then
fndrow = Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47").Find(What:=maxvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
Else
fndrow = Sheets("Resumo").Range("J" & prevrow & ":J47").Find(What:=maxvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
End If

Dim vendor As String
vendor = Sheets("Resumo").Range("G" & CStr(fndrow))

Sheets("os melhores").Range("F" & CStr(copyrow)) = maxvalue
If InStr(vendor, " ") <> 0 Then
Sheets("os melhores").Range("G" & CStr(copyrow)) = Left(vendor, InStr(vendor, " "))
Sheets("os melhores").Range("H" & CStr(copyrow)) = Right(vendor, InStr(vendor, " "))
Else
Sheets("os melhores").Range("G" & CStr(copyrow)) = Sheets("Resumo").Range("G" & CStr(fndrow))
End If

prevval = maxvalue
prevrow = fndrow
copyrow = copyrow + 1

Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is giving some variables not declared

Comment: Changed Sheet names to Resumo and  os melhores. Please check now.

Comment: I had already done that and had do add: Dim i As Long and Dim fndrow As Long. Its working like a charm! There is only one thing. The vendor name is the full name, and i need to pass just the first and last. Can you help do it? Thanks in advance !

Comment: are they separated by a space .Any delimiter ?

Comment: All the names are separated by a space, like"Mary Jonas de Oliveira", without the brackets.

Comment: The first name is OK, but the last name is not complete in all of them. For instance "DIOGO ALBERTO NEVES CONCEICAO" it gives DIOGO and in the other cell "CEICAO". "CLAUDIA CATARINA SILVA REI LOBA", is "CLAUDIA" and in the other cell "REI LOBA".

Answer (score 0):

Its Solved with the precious help of KannanRG.
I changed the right of this line:

```
Sheets("os melhores").Range("H" & CStr(copyrow)) = Right(vendor, Len(vendor) - InStrRev(vendor, " "))
```

The right value is equal to the lenght of full name, minus the lenght of last name.

Thanks to all that have read and help me to solve this issue.